# Javafx adding dynamically pane to vbox Duplicate Children error

Tags: javafx, duplicates, children, pane, vbox

I have a pane with a label, a text field and a combo box inside a VBox in fxml file. Let´s call it tempPane.
In the same stage I have a button.
Once the button is pressed I need to add to the VBox a pane exactly the same as tempPane. This is, adding dynamically a pane to the VBOX.
I am able to add individual controls such as buttons or labels or text fields to the VBox, but I can´t obtain the same results when trying to add this new pane.

Part of the controller code:

```
@FXML
private Pane tempPane;

@FXML 
private Button btnAddNewPane;;

@FXML
private VBox vBox;

@FXML
void addNewPane(ActionEvent event) {

    ...
        Pane newPane = new Pane();
        newPane = tempPane;
        // New ID is set to the newPane, this String (NewID) should be 
        //different each time button is pressed
        newPane.setId(newID);
        vBox.getChildren().add(newPane);
    ...
}
```

And the error I´m getting is:

```
Exception in thread "JavaFX Application Thread" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Children: duplicate children added: parent = VBox[id=filterBox]
at javafx.graphics/javafx.scene.Parent$3.onProposedChange(Parent.java:580)
at javafx.base/com.sun.javafx.collections.VetoableListDecorator.add(VetoableListDecorator.java:206)
at com.sener.dbgui.controller.SearchController$1.run(SearchController.java:53)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$9(PlatformImpl.java:418)
at java.base/java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.javafx.application.PlatformImpl.lambda$runLater$10(PlatformImpl.java:417)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.InvokeLaterDispatcher$Future.run(InvokeLaterDispatcher.java:96)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication._runLoop(Native Method)
at javafx.graphics/com.sun.glass.ui.win.WinApplication.lambda$runLoop$3(WinApplication.java:175)
at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:844)
```

So, why am I getting this duplicate children error? I´m changing the newPane ID before adding it to the VBox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Pane newPane = new Pane();
newPane = tempPane;
...
vBox.getChildren().add(newPane);
```

This code does create a new `Pane` (first line) but immediately drops the new instance by overwriting it with the old one (second line).

The error happens since the contract of `Node` does not allow it to be placed twice in a scene and you're adding the same `Pane` that is already a child of `vBox` again. Modifying the `id` property does not change that fact.

You need to create a new copy of the subscene rooted at `tempPane` if this is supposed to work.

You could create a custom `Pane` for this scene:

#### subFXML.fxml

```xml
<fx:root xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" type="javafx.scene.layout.Pane">
    <!-- content of tempPane from old fxml goes here -->
    ...
    <Button fx:id="btnAddNewPane" />
    ...
</fx:root>
```

```
public class MyPane extends Pane {

    public MyPane() {
        FXMLLoader loader = getClass().getResource("subFXML.fxml");
        loader.setRoot(this);
        loader.setController(this);

        try {
            fxmlLoader.load();
        } catch (IOException exception) {
            throw new RuntimeException(exception);
        }
    }

    @FXML
    private Button btnAddNewPane;

    public void setOnAction(EventHandler<ActionEvent> handler) {
        btnAddNewPane.setOnAction(handler);
    }

    public EventHandler<ActionEvent> getOnAction() {
        return btnAddNewPane.getOnAction();
    }
}
```

#### old fxml

Be sure to import MyPane.

```xml
...
<VBox fx:id="vBox">
    <children>
        <!-- replace tempPane with MyPane -->
        <MyPane onAction="#addNewPane"/>
    </children>
</VBox>
...
```

#### old controller

```
@FXML
private VBox vBox;

@FXML
void addNewPane(ActionEvent event) {

    ...
        MyPane newPane = new MyPane();
        newPane.setId(newID); // Don't know why setting the CSS id is necessary here
        newPane.setOnAction(this::addNewPane); // set onAction property
        vBox.getChildren().add(newPane);
    ...
}
```

Comment: I keep getting the "Type mismatch: cannot convert from URL to FXMLLoader" error, so I´m not able to test this code.

Comment: Yes, I thought the id was related to the fx:id if the fxml pane, but it is indeed the CSS id.

Comment: On the other hand, I need to have a unique button to add filter and must be in the main stage, not in each panel added. The problem is that I still cannot test this code for the mismatch type error I´m getting. OK, just added   FXMLLoader loader =  new FXMLLoader(getClass().getResource("subFXML.fxml")); and it works...Let´s see if I can test it. thank you!

Comment: Great!, this worked. I had to make some workaround to fix the only "one button" in stage but it works great. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

It is written in your comments already why you are getting duplicate ID.

> // New ID is set to the newPane, this String (NewID) should be
>
> //different each time button is pressed

You are passing the same string as a parameter.

```
newPane.setId("NewID");
```

try using a dynamically generated and unique id for each pane.

```
String newId; //generate the id by user input or internally
    newPane.setId(newId);
```

Comment: Yes I understand it, I will change the "newID" to newID in the question so there´s no confussion. But even when adding the pane for the first time the same error appears. So this seems to be not the problem.

Comment: 'newPane = tempPane;' by this line you are referencing to the same old pane not the new one. I think it should be the other way around.

Comment: But what I want is to have a pane identical to the tempPane from the FXML. I have printed in console the IDs for the tempPane and newPane and there´s something funny. Before the setID the tempPane ID is correct and after setID both panes change their ID...

Comment: I don't think you are getting exactly how this works. newPane = tempPane by this line you are just copying the reference of the same object over again and again. and yes as they both now point to the same object if you change the id of one both will change.

Comment: Ok, thank you for the explanation. So, how could I create a new pane with all the elements of tempPane?